# Использование дефиса

Tags: орфография, однородные-члены, раздельно-дефис, слитно-дефис

**"Подпишись на разные паблики, рассылки, YouTube- и Telegram-каналы".**

Правильно ли оформлен первый однородный член c дефисом, под которым подразумеваются YouTube-каналы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если такие слова, как YouTube-канал и Telegram-канал, существуют, то «висячий» дефис применительно к ним использован корректно.

> § 112. Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, 
>   если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют «висячим», напр.: шарико- и роликоподшипники; лит- и изокружки; кино-, теле- и видеофильмы; не двух-, а трёхэтажный дом; не только англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты; как водо-, так и газоснабжение; до- или послеперестроечные процессы; либо теле-, либо радиопередача; обер- и унтер-офицеры. Как видно из примеров, употребление висячего дефиса не зависит от слитного или дефисного написания сложных слов.
>   ([Дефис](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59))